# Escape list of JVM arguments in .bat file correctly

Tags: file, batch-file, jvm, arguments

I have a bat-file in which I'm trying to pass the JVM a list of non proxy hosts via "-Dhttp.nonProxyHosts". The file already contains a list of arguments and if I try to just add the one in question like this:

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
...
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.company.com|localhost|127.0.0.1"
```

Windows tells me "command 'localhost' not found".

And if I try to escape it like

```
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.company.com^|localhost^|127.0.0.1"
```

The result is pretty much the same, so how DO I pass this list correctly?

Cheers
Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suppose the problem isn't the `SET`, it's later when you use the `JAVA_OPTS` variable.

The best way is to use delayed expansion here, as it's ignore special characters at all.

```
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "JAVA_OPTS=-Xms64M -Xmx1024M -XX:MaxPermSize=256M"
set "JAVA_OPTS=%JAVA_OPTS% -Dhttp.nonProxyHosts=*.company.com|localhost|127.0.0.1"

java.exe !JAVA_OPTS!
```